# How do I deal with tags for a docker stack deploy?

Tags: deployment, docker-swarm, stack

I've got a docker compose (3) file which I'm doing a `docker stack deploy` on. I do this in a Jenkins pipeline.

The way I deal with tags is that i set an environment variable `API_TAG` and the (relevant part of the) corresponding docker compose file looks like this.

```
version: '3'

services:
  api:
    image: registry:5000/api:${API_TAG}
```

How do I deal with tags for other services in that stack / docker compose file which I did not just build? The pipeline I'm dealing with only builds an api application, not the three databases it depends on. However, these databases have specific tags as well (not just `latest`). Do I really  need to query the swarm cluster for the currently running services and tags for those database so that the `docker stack deploy` does not mess up anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, your stack compose file should container all services your running as containers for that app, so yes, if you have a database container that needs to be included, it should be in the compose file and you manage the version/tag running in that compose file.

The idea here is you could design a compose file, (or compose file and [override file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/)) that work with `docker-compose up` for local development, and `docker stack deploy` for swarm deployments.

An alternative, but IMO more complex way, is to run other services in their on compose/stack file and use manually-created overlay networks to ensure they are all on the same docker virtual networks.

Comment: Thanks @Bret Fisher. I went with what you're suggesting in the second paragraph. The compose file now use env variables for tags, and Jenkins now just queries the swarm for a given stack's service tags. Relevant env variables are then populated with these tags, and the compose file can fallback to these env variables for all services that is not being built in the Jenkins Pipeline. This means they will remain unchanged. Will upvote and accept your answer, I appreciate your feedback!